# Point everytime someone clicks a button

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm making a small quiz (5 questions) where the user gets 1 to 5 points on a question. There are 5 answers per question so 5 buttons.

I don't want 5 different activities so I thought about changing the textview in buttons + the question when the user clickes on a random answer/button. Every button has 1 to 5 points, but it's always the same button. So for example if the first question he clicks on button1 it gives 1 point, but on the second question if he clicks on button 4 he gets 4 points. Makes sense?

So my problem is my if statements are not working and I don't know why. It's probably something really small, but it's my first time programming for android so yeah. :(

What's wrong with my code? I don't got any errors. When I click on button1 it changes to "Last one" and score is showing.

```
  public class Vraag1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

 Button a;
 Button b;
 Button c;
 Button d;
 Button e; 
 TextView scoreatm; 
 int int1 = 0;
 int int2 = 0;
 int int3 = 0;
 int int4 = 0;
 int int5 = 0;
 int intwelk = 0;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_vraag1);

        a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        a.setOnClickListener(this);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

        c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        c.setOnClickListener(this);

        d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        d.setOnClickListener(this);

        e = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        e.setOnClickListener(this);  

}

public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

      switch (v.getId()) {
         case R.id.button1: 

                if (intwelk == 0){
                    intwelk = 1;
                    int1 = 1; //1 point
                    a.setText("Change in this");        
                }

                if (intwelk == 1){  
                    intwelk = 2;
                    int2 = 1; //1 point
                    a.setText("Now this"); 
                }

                if (intwelk == 2){      
                    intwelk = 3;
                    int3 = 1; //1 point
                    a.setText("And this");      
                }

                if (intwelk == 3){          
                    intwelk = 4;
                    int4 = 1; //1 point
                    a.setText("Last one");          
                }

                if (intwelk == 4){
                    intwelk = 0;
                    int5 = 1; //1 point

                    showScore();
                }

          break;
         case R.id.button2:

                int1 = 2;

          break;
         case R.id.button3:

                int1 = 3;

          break;
         case R.id.button4:

                int1 = 4;

          break;
         case R.id.button5:

                int1 = 5;

          break;

      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow. Just when I posted this I figured it out, great.

Needed to start with intwelk == 4 and then intwelk == 3 then intwelk == 2. Etc.

Makes sense, because code reads from top to bottom. I guess it's getting late!

Comment: Ofcourse, that would make even more sense...... This question should be deleted for stupidity.